# Alfresco callling wrong ports after applying amps

Tags: alfresco, ports

Hello i am having a very strange problem that happens when i apply amps in my local alfresco installation. The process of applying amps goes smoothly, and alfresco starts up normally, but if i try to open share the following exception happens:

```
2014-05-27 17:53:49,205  INFO  [webscripts.connector.RemoteClient] [http-apr-8584-exec-5] Exception calling (GET) http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/remoteadm/has/alfresco/site-data/template-types/org/alfresco/simple-guest.xml?s=sitestore
```

Has anyone got any ideas why is this happening? I know for sure that the problem is in the port share is trying to call, because i do not have it set up on 8080, but i do not know why is share calling this port?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did the AMPs come from? Is it possible that one of them comes with a context file or properties file that overrides the port?

Comment: Nop, amps are created by me, and they contain some custom webscripts and a custom object model. I am absolutely puzzled by this!

Comment: Where/what did you change before to change the default port for Share to use?

Comment: I set the ports when i was installing Alfresco through the installer, and i checked the alfresco-global.propertis and the ports are correctly set in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AMP file must contain one share-config-custom.xml under which one of the config is pointing to this 8080 port. This issue is most probably because of that only.

1. So, extract your entire AMP.
2. Check for that 8080 port reference.
3. Replace it with port you are using for alfresco.
4. Again create AMP.
5. Apply new AMP (Change version of AMP to next version)

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, i am sorry for late answering i somehow missed your answer! Yep there i have a share-config-custom.xml and it turns out that it had a property with port 8080 specified, so i modified it and it works!